# Why does calculating volume using cubic inches gives different answer than with using cubic centimeters?

Tags: volume, unit-of-measure

Length: $8$'

Width: $2$'

Height: $7$cm

---

$243.84$cm × $60.96$cm × $7$cm = $104051.4048$ cm³

$104051.4048$ cm³ = **$104.051$ liters**

---

$96$" × $24$" × $1.181$" = $2721.024$ inches³

$2721.024$ inches³ = **$44.59$ liters**

---

$104$L $\ne$ $44$L

What have I done wrong and which is correct? Please show the appropriate calculation and conversions.

I'm using google calculator and converting by typing in google search bar (i.e. $2721$ inches to liters =). The cm and inch conversions were taken the same (i.e. Google search bar: $8$' in cm =).

I am guessing that there is an error in Google's conversions when asked to convert from the search bar.

Comment: Well 7 cm is quite a bit more than 1.2 inches, so there's one problem...

Comment: Fortunately that is the only problem here.

Comment: Wow ok. Can't believe I didn't see that. Case closed.

Answer (score 1):

As said:
Length: $8'$ or $243.84cm$

Width: $2'$ or $60.96cm$

Height: $0.229659'$ or $7cm$

$8'×2'× 0.229659'=3.674544 cubic foot=104.05149874L$

$243.84cm × 60.96cm × 7cm = 104051.4048 cm³=104.051405L$

accounting for rounding it's relieving to say that our measurement system has not screwed us over.